# Remove files older than 18 months in UNIX (date in file name, not timestamp)

Tags: unix, ksh

I want to delete log files which are older than 18 months from a directory. But deletion should not be based on the timestamp of file.
It should be based on the name of file.
Kindly help us to remove these files?

S14444225.SLS.20150131073838 (No need to Delete),
C14444210.ITM.20150131073838 (No need to Delete),
O14444216.OUT.20150131073838(No need to Delete),
S14444225.SLS.20130131073838(need to be Deleted),
C14444210.ITM.20130131073838(need to be Deleted),
O14444216.OUT.20130131073838(need to be Deleted)

Comment: what have you tried so far to do this?  What shell script language do you already know (perl, python, ruby, bash?)

Comment: find . *abc* -mtime +546 -exec rm {} \; But this will be removed based on system created timestamp which i don't want it, Can you please share your ideas on that?

Comment: I don't do ksh but the structure of the script would be for each file extract the date part from the filename.  Compare the date part with a cut off date and if it is less than the cut off delete it.  Numeric compare should work fine as the format of the dates is yyymmdd